# SQL Query result error: The query operator 'ElementAt' is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am trying to loop over SQL Query result with **do-while** loop, but there are problems with indexing of the result variable.

The problem is on the line with `while (selectQuery.ElementAt(i).Source != user.Item1 && selectQuery.ElementAt(i).UserID != user.Item2 && i<selectQuery.Count());`

So my question is: **How can I index the sql query result variable?**

Here's my code:

```
        //------------------Database connection initialization--------------------------
        string m_dbConnestionString = "Server=aaa; Database=bbb; uid=ccc; pwd=ddd; Trusted_Connection=True;"
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(m_dbConnectionString);
        Table<Central> m_myTable = db.GetTable<Central>()
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------            

        int i = -1;

        var selectQuery =
            from central in m_myTable 
            select central;


        foreach (var row in selectQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0};  {1}",row.DisplayName, row.Email);
        }


        foreach (var user in allMailusers) // btw, allMailUsers is List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string>> 
        {

            do
            {

                i += 1;

            } while (selectQuery.ElementAt(i).Source != user.Item1 && selectQuery.ElementAt(i).UserID != user.Item2 && i<selectQuery.Count()); 

            if (selectQuery.ElementAt(i).Source != user.Item1 && selectQuery.ElementAt(i).UserID != user.Item2) // if true, insert into DB
            {
                // create new instance of Central
                Central c1 = new test1.Central();

                // fill up c1 with values
                c1.UserID       = selectQuery.ElementAt(i).UserID;
                c1.Source       = selectQuery.ElementAt(i).Source;
                c1.DisplayName  = selectQuery.ElementAt(i).DisplayName;
                c1.Email        = selectQuery.ElementAt(i).Email;
                c1.Phone        = selectQuery.ElementAt(i).Phone;

                // insert into db
                m_myDb.Centrals.InsertOnSubmit(c1);
                m_myDb.SubmitChanges();

            } // end if 

            i = -1;
         } // end of foreach
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, note that every time you enumerate over an `IQueryable` (which is the resulting type of you linq expression), you are hitting the database again.  Instead, grab a local cache of your query by doing

```
var result = selectQuery.ToArray();
```

or something similar.

Once you do that, `result.ElementAt` should work, and you are only hitting the database once.

Example:

```
foreach (var row in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0};  {1}",row.DisplayName, row.Email);
}
```

Since you were trying to use `ElementAt` on an `IQueryable`, the Entity Framework was trying to translate that into a SQL command, which it doesn't know how to do, hence the error.